# Can a SOAP web service be consumed without a WSDL?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soa, osb

I mean lets say, we don't have any knowledge about the WSDL to a particular web service and we want to consume it somehow. Is it possible? Maybe twerking the URL a bit. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes it's possible, if you know what request to send. SOAP is just a transport protocol

Comment: @tomredfern But if I dont have the WSDL, how will I know the URI endpoint to hit? Please clear the concept. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible: 
suppose you have access to a private's company network and you have enough knowledge of the company. You can use service discovery mechanisms. 
You could scan the network trying to find SOAP protocol msgs on the fly.

Usually if you are legally hired you get access to companys information, then the architecture, then tools used and bingo you can narrow down your quest to get URI endpoints of running web services.